# Derivation of chi-square with 2 degrees of freedom

Tags: probability

My failed attempt:

Let $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ independent; $Z = X^2+Y^2$

Let $M = ((x,y)  |  x^2+y^2<z^2)$

$$F_z(z^2) = P(Z<z^2) = P(X^2+Y^2<z^2) = \int\int_{M} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}e^\frac{-y^2}{2}dxdy $$

Switching to polar coordinates we get:

$$F_z(z^2) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{z}[\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^\frac{-r^2}{2}  d\theta]dr = \int_{0}^{z}e^\frac{-r^2}{2}dr = 2\pi \int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{2\pi} e^\frac{-r^2}{2}dr = 2\pi( \phi(z) - \frac{1}{2})  $$

where $\phi(.)$ stands for CDF of standard normal. Differentiating both sides I get:

$$f_z(z^2)2z=2\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt2\pi}e^\frac{-z^2}{2}$$

and thus: $$f(z) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2z}e^\frac{-z}{2} , z\geq0$$

Would anyone be so kind to point out the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot that when you make the coordinate transformation, the Jacobian of the transformation is not $1$ but $r$.  That is to say, the differential area element in Cartesian coordinates $dA = dx \, dy$ becomes $r \, dr \, d\theta$ in polar coordinates.